# Can't find string resources in 'Design' tab of Android Studio XML file

Tags: java, android, string

So the main issue i am having right now, is that Android Studio won't recognize some of the string resources i have made in the Strings.xml file of my project. More specifically in the 'Design' tab.

[As you can see here, the (highlighted) string is there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h83qy.png)

[But back in the 'Design' tab, when i go to look for the string, it doesn't recognize that it even exists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMehj.png)

I have tried removing the TextView and replacing it with a new one, with no luck unfortunately.

And yes, i am aware that my naming of strings are far from optimal.

Comment: why do you need designer to add the string

Comment: besides, if you goto Build>Clean Project, you will see the string again

Comment: How else would i add the string? 
I'm pretty new to Android Studio in general, but this is at least the way i'm familiar with adding strings.

Comment: Build>Clean Project worked, thanks! 
Sorry if this was a dumb question, but i couldn't find any other questions with the same problem. 

If you don't mind me asking, how is it that it showed up after i pressed "Clean Project"?

Comment: some times, newly added string do not get indexed. so you either restart studio or rebuild the project. hope this helps.

Comment: I also posted an answer on how to add string values to TextView using XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML file, add the desired string like this

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/inspireTxt"
   android:text="@string/inspirational" />
```

The designer will not always get updated. But if you code it in XML like this, it will work. 
Second, if you still want to use Designer, try cleaning and rebuilding the project.
sometimes the newly added values do not get indexed.

Hope this helps.